# Starting an Ingress service on Docker for Mac

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm, docker-for-mac

Using:

```
kubectl expose deployment <Name-Of-Servce> --name=loadbalancer --port=8080 --target-port=8080 --type=LoadBalancer
```

The `kubectl get services` is showing pending:

```
loadbalancer                 LoadBalancer   <x.x.x.x>   <pending>     8080:32670/TCP   2m
```

Before Docker surported Kubernetes, I could use MiniKube and Helm:

```
helm install stable/jenkins
kubectl get services // To get the service name
minikube service original-llama-jenkins // << The service name
```

Now that we have Docker for Mac(Edge) supporting Kubernetes, how do you add an `EXTERNAL-IP`?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Unless something seriously magical has happened with "Docker for Mac," then the `type: LoadBalancer` is only designed for a cloud environment, where the Ingress controller can [provision a cloud load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) (i.e. AWS's ELB, GKE's ... whatever they use).

That said, one can see from your output that kubernetes has behaved as if it was `type: NodePort` (with your specific example showing that port `32670` goes to port `8080` on your Service). It's unclear whether you can just use that NodePort-ish port as-is, or whether the Service in "pending" state somehow means traffic will not route as expected. I guess maybe just try it?

Or you can skip the pretense and create the Service legitimately of `type: NodePort`, and then you and kubernetes will be on the same page about what is happening.

The other way you can chose to do things is run an in-cluster Ingress controller, such as [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/nginx-0.9.0#nginx-ingress-controller), and use virtual-hosting to expose all your services on just one port. That can be far more convenient if you have a lot of Services to expose, but it would likely be too big of a headache to set up just for one or two of them.

Comment: As commented below, Docker for Mac Kubernetes *does* support LoadBalancer, so this answer should not be the accepted one.

Comment: hey @Matthew L Daniel , i am using kubernetes on docker for mac, i have created a service and installed nginx controller but now i am not able to hit nginx controller like what IP i need to add it in my hosts file so that requests will reach to nginx which will redirect to  corresponding service , can you please help me

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 18):

Both type LoadBalancer and NodePort work on Docker for Mac Kubernetes. It's a lovely bit of magic, actually. Just hit localhost:[port]. For NodePort, a port is automatically assigned unless specified in the service definition. For type LoadBalancer, it is also specified in the service definition. Note that in using LoadBalancer, the status from `kubectl` will be shown as `<pending>` for EXTERNAL-IP but it does work.

This guy notes that it's exposed through vpnkit though I think another source would be helpful:

https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes

Edit: updated because Kubernetes is now available in stable versions of DfM.

Comment: That sounds great,that version of Docker for Mac are you using?

Comment: Edited to clarify that k8s for DFM requires the edge release for now.