# Nginx Ingress does not route on Docker for Mac, the Address field of ingress is still null

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, docker-for-mac

I am trying to create a [simple fanout ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) with mac docker desktop. I am using the example from [here](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html).

I have followed [the installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-for-mac) and confirmed nginx-ingress-controller deployment running

```
cc-backend ➤ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx                                                                                                                  
NAME                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-54f689bd-64sp5   1/1       Running   0          6h

cc-backend ➤ kubectl get deployment -n ingress-nginx                                                                                                            
NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller   1         1         1            1           6h
```

But the Address field is null and localhost is unreachable.

```
cc-backend ➤ kubectl describe ingress                                                                                                                           
Name:             simple-fanout-example
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /apple    apple-service:5678 (<none>)
        /banana   banana-service:5678 (<none>)
Annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  54m   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/simple-fanout-example

cc-backend ➤ curl -kL http://localhost                                                                                                                          
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused


kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.96.200.3   <pending>     80:31036/TCP,443:32756/TCP   1d
```

What else did I miss ?

Comment: kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx still external ip as pending state ?

Comment: right and that was my question what else did I miss here.

Comment: are you running this locally ?

Comment: yes it's that obvious from my question ?

Comment: as much i know ingress if load balancer there it will create load balancer on cloud (aws, GCP).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244233/starting-an-ingress-service-on-docker-for-mac

Comment: The simple fanout example from kubernetes docs uses `host: foo.bar.com`. If you have done this as well, ensure `foo.bar.com` routes to your `localhost`. Suggest adding `127.0.0.1 foo.bar.com` to `/etc/hosts`.

Docker for mac should add `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal` by default. It's also an option to update your ingress host to this one.